# torch hub error for yolov5 in ubuntu aws ec2 instance

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pytorch, yolov5

I install torch and open cv like this

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

pip install opencv-python
```

then
I run this code in ubuntu aws ec2 instance

```
import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')

# Image
im = 'car.jpg'

# Inference
results = model(im)

results.pandas().xyxy[0]
```

but I get this error

```
Using cache found in /home/ubuntu/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/web/lib/objd/objd.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
  File "/home/ubuntu/web/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 542, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/web/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 572, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 93, in yolov5s
    return _create('yolov5s', pretrained, channels, classes, autoshape, _verbose, device)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 33, in _create
    from models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
  File "/home/ubuntu/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/ubuntu/web/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/ubuntu/web/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

how to solve this, because if I run this code in my local computer, running well